# How to divide text view in equal spaces

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout

How to divide text view in equal spaces 
how to use remaining white space to divide between text view
image is given below

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/ocean"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" 
     />


<TextView
    android:text="You're invited!"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:background="#009688" />

<TextView
    android:text="Bonfire at the beach"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="#009678" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[output is coming this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJX8H.jpg)

Comment: Please share expected output

Answer (score 0):

You can add `android:weightSum="3"` to your parent view and adding `android:layout_weight="1"` for every child.

**This is the layout:**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:weightSum="3">

<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/rose"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />


<TextView
    android:text="You're invited!"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:background="#009688" />

<TextView
    android:text="Bonfire at the beach"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="#009678" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]